# I have a problem with ToolBar and SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am working on android app and designing with the help of androidx. I put SearchView into the Toolbar and I want that by clicking any point on ToolBar, the searchView would activate (currently, only by clicking icon of searchbar it activates.
This is my code in activity_main XML file

[I want that by clicking any ToolBar point, SearchView to activate and let user enter the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaCg0.png)

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by code, add clicklistener to toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_id);
        SearchView searchView=findViewById(R.id.search_id);
        toolbar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            searchView.setIconified(false);

        });
```